# How to access windows file server from linux

Tags: windows, samba

We have a windows file server with an address like this:

```
\\bioinf-filesrv2.mycompany.fr\cluster15
```

How can I access it from Linux?

On a Ubuntu 14.04 I tried to access this through nautilus, but it crashed. Here is the crash report:

http://pastebin.mozilla.org/5533388

Comment: Please give us some more information. What Linux are you running? Do you have a graphical interface? Have you tried opening the file browser (just clicking on any directory) and checking the network section? Also, [we expect users](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to first try and solve their issue themselves before posting here. Did you try any of the [several thousand results](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=How+to+access+windows+file+server+from+linux) you get when copy/pasting your question's title into a search engine? How did they fail?

Answer (score 23):

Assuming a recent Linux, do this:

```
$ mount -t cifs //bioinf-filesrv2.mycompany.fr/cluster15 /mnt
```

Which will mount it at `/mnt`. You will need sufficient privilege (or be root).

If you need to add credentials, try:

```
$ mount -t cifs -o username=myuser,password=mypass //bioinf-filesrv2.mycompany.fr/cluster15 /mnt
```

You may need to install a package from your distro's repository called `cifs-utils` but, hopefully, it would already be there as part of the standard install.

Comment: It is secure to put password on the command line?

Comment: Only as secure as where the command-line is. If you're putting them in a script then they are as secure as the permissions in that script. There is an alternative which is to use a credentials file. This is described [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html).

Comment: On Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), I get a `bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.` UPDATE: OK, I probably need to `apt install cifs-utils`...

Comment: If you don't want to put your password in the command line, just use `mount -t cifs -o username=myuser //bioinf-filesrv2.mycompany.fr/cluster15 /mnt` and then you will be asked to enter your password.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest adding it to your `/etc/fstab`, so it's online as soon as you boot. Mine has a (long) line reading:

```
//1.2.3.4/share_name/    /media/mount_point    cifs    uid=1000,guid=1000,rw,credentials=/etc/cifspasswd    0    0
```

- The first field is the address and share name.
- The second field is the mount point on your system (the folder must exist).
- `cifs` is the type of the file system for any Windows share.
- `uid=1000,guid=1000,rw` means that anyone on the system can access this share
- `credentials=/etc/cifspasswd` means that that credentials found in `/etc/cifspasswd` will be used to authenticate access to the share on the Windows server.

This credential file should contain the username and password necessary for accessing the Windows share, i.e.

```
username=foo
password=bar
```

As `/etc/fstab` is (usually) readable by other users of the system, you can create the file as root and `chmod go-=rwx` to remove access for other users, to protect your password.

**Caveat** If you boot your system and the server isn't available, Linux will wait a bit during the boot sequence before giving up.

Comment: This worked great for me, except the options part of the line should be: `uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,credentials=/etc/cifspasswd`. Note that the `guid` was changed to `gid`.

Comment: Oh, and I had to change the file system section to use `\040` for spaces (gotta love Windows admins). Got that info from [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316017/how-do-i-specify-a-label-path-with-spaces-in-etc-fstab).

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu click alt+f2.

Type `smb://bioinf-filesrv2.mycompany.fr/cluster15`. Enter.

See the new mount in Nautilus.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29167/3-easy-ways-to-connect-to-windows-shared-folders-from-linux/